# Center Div/Text in Fieldset Dynamically

Tags: html, css

Having trouble centering text vertically in a fieldset. This particularly when a sibling is hidden.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/EL_C905/q8dm03pu/16/) is what the code should looks like when the sibling is showing:

```css
    #title {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    #definition {
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 5%;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      font-size: 1.5vmax;
    }
    
    hr {
      color: white;
      background-color: white;
      width: 80%;
      height: 1px;
    }
    
    #formulaLine {
      color: white;
      background-color: white;
      height: 1px;
    }
    
    section#formula {
      width: auto;
      max-width: 70%;
      background: #393e46;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 5px 10px rgb(24, 23, 23);
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 5% auto;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 2vmax 1vmin;
    }
    
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p .center {
      margin-top: 5%;
    }
    
    .tBox {
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      min-height: 400px;
      max-height: 500px;
      background-color: #222831;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 40px auto;
      align-content: center;
      color: #eeeeee;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .legend {
      padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
      background: #d65a31;
      border-radius: 25px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 200px;
      font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <fieldset class="tBox">
        <legend class="legend">Definition</legend>
        <div id="definition">Answers if we did what we said we would do. BECAUSE IT'S LONG I'LL ADD EXTRA TEXT TO SHOW MULTI-LINE EFFECT</div>
        <div>
          <hr>
          <section id="formula">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="column center" style="margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 3%;">Formula:</p>
              <div class="column center">
                <p>∑ # completed tasks in month 'A' (from month 'B' schedule)</p>
                <hr id="formulaLine">
                <p>∑ # tasks forecased to finish in month 'A'</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Problem is that when hiding the formula sibling (I am using React), the definition doesn't center. It looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/EL_C905/pjeaxhb0/8/):

```css
    #title {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    
    #definition {
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 5%;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      font-size: 1.5vmax;
    }
    
    hr {
      color: white;
      background-color: white;
      width: 80%;
      height: 1px;
    }
    
    #formulaLine {
      color: white;
      background-color: white;
      height: 1px;
    }
    
    section#formula {
      width: auto;
      max-width: 70%;
      background: #393e46;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 5px 10px rgb(24, 23, 23);
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 5% auto;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 2vmax 1vmin;
    }
    
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p .center {
      margin-top: 5%;
    }
    
    .tBox {
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      min-height: 400px;
      max-height: 500px;
      background-color: #222831;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 40px auto;
      align-content: center;
      color: #eeeeee;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .legend {
      padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
      background: #d65a31;
      border-radius: 25px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 200px;
      font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <fieldset class="tBox">
        <legend class="legend">Definition</legend>
        <div id="definition">MY TEXT HERE. IT CAN GET LONG. MULTI-LINE. HERE'S MORE TO FILL THIS OUT. LONG LONG LONG.</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Note that the CSS for this second example is the same as above. What am I doing wrong? I've tried `Top`, `Float`, and a variety of other options. None seem to work.

Comment: Sorry for the repetitive changes to my answer. I wanted to ensure it was a better quality for future readers. My final answer is below and includes options for using `position: absolute`, `display: flex`, and `:only-child` since I don't know exactly how the formula is added or removed from the container. Best of luck on your future endeavors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adjusting your markup to support using `:only-child` in `CSS`. This is a `pseudo-class` that represents an element without any siblings. Definitely give [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) a review for some other examples.

```
/* Selects each <p>, but only if it is the only child of its parent. */
p:only-child {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

It's pretty useful for situations just like this and the implementation wouldn't take very many changes.

```js
var formula = document.createElement("P");
formula.innerText = "This element represents your formula being added to the container which removes the styles applied with :only-child.";
var active = false;
function toggleFormula() {
 active = !active;
 document.getElementById("legend").innerText = active ? "Click here to hide formula." :
                    "Click here to show formula.";
 
 let tbox = document.getElementById("t-box");
 if (active)
  tbox.appendChild(formula);
 else
  tbox.removeChild(formula);
}
```

```css
.container { position: relative; }
.legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
  background: #d65a31;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-size: 3vmax 2vmin;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#definition {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60%;
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
}
#definition:only-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.tBox {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 500px;
  background-color: #222831;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  align-content: center;
  color: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#definition {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 60%;
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
}
#definition:only-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <legend id="legend" class="legend" onclick="toggleFormula();">Click here to show formula.</legend>
 <fieldset id="t-box" class="tBox">
  <div id="definition">Answers if we did what we said we would do. BECAUSE IT'S LONG I'LL ADD EXTRA TEXT TO SHOW MULTI-LINE EFFECT</div>
 </fieldset>
</div>
```

Alternative options are using `position: absolute` or `display: flex`:

```
/* Absolute Version */
#definition.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Flex Version */
.tBox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of a pseudo-class, but from a simplicity standpoint, the alternative worked like a charm. I wound up using the absolute version.

Answer (score 0):

With your exiting code, just adding few properties to your css will be an easy fix. Flex properties are really helpful in these scenarios, align-items: center will align all elements inside the div to align vertically and justify-content: center will align items horizontally.

```
section#formula {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    background: #393e46;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 5px 10px rgb(24, 23, 23);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2vmax 1vmin;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.center {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

You can see it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/Lk05tfe8/2/)

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for the response. While this centers the formula section, it doesn't quite answer the question, which is to center the definition dynamically based on whether the formula is present or not.